# How to add class after append in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

Back again with another question about my todo-app.

Currently the development is going good. It's now possible to add todo's, delete todo's, edit todo's and 'finish' todo's.

You can see the result so far here: http://todoapp.lusenet.com/

The app contains to views: the TodoView and the AppView. The AppView renders the application using the TodoView.

When the application gets loaded, the `initialize` function of the AppView gets called. This is what happens there:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.input = this.$('#addTodo');
    this.todoCollection = new app.TodoCollection(); // Create collection
    this.todoCollection.fetch({reset: true}); // Fetch items

    this.listenTo(this.todoCollection, 'reset', this.addAll);
    this.listenTo(this.todoCollection, 'add', this.addOne);
}
```

So I create a new collection, fetch the models which are in there, which fires the `reset` event. `reset` then calls the `addAll` function.

This is the `addAll` function:

```
addAll: function(){
    var i = 0,
        self = this;

    this.$('#todoList').html(''); // clean the todo list
    this.todoCollection.each(function(todo){
        i++;
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.addOne(todo);
        }, 200*i￼);
    });
}
```

This function just loops through the entire collection and calls `addOne` for every model. This is done in a timeout so that the models get appended one after another.

This is the `addOne` function:

```
addOne: function(todo){
    var view = new app.TodoView({model: todo}).render();
    $(view.el).appendTo('#todoList');
}
```

Here my troubles start. The `addOne` function appends a model the list, which is completely fine. When I add this CSS to the model:

```
-webkit-transition: all 2000ms ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 2000ms ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 2000ms ease-out;
-o-transition: all 2000ms ease-out;
transition: all 2000ms ease-out;
bottom:-2px;
opacity: 0;
```

The model is hidden when added, which is what I want. I figured, if I call `addClass` after the append, I can animate the model. So I added one line of code to make the `addOne` function like this:

```
addOne: function(todo){
    var view = new app.TodoView({model: todo}).render();
    $(view.el).appendTo('#todoList');
    view.$el.addClass('show');
}
```

This works, only the model already has the class 'show' when I append it, so no fade in happens. How can I add the class after the append is done? Or am I just doing it completely wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the browser doesn't have enough time to actually insert the element into the DOM before class is added.

I'd try using `setTimeout`, and you really don't need large values there.

```
addOne: function(todo){
    var view = new app.TodoView({model: todo}).render();
    view.$el.appendTo('#todoList');
    setTimeout(function(){
        view.$el.addClass('show');
    }, 40);
}
```

This is actually a known trick, and [some people even call it with 0 timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/132829).

Comment: This does work! Only weird that it has to be done this way.. Any way to just make a call to a function when appendTo is done?

Comment: That is actually something about how browser handle element insertion and processing javascript that comes next. I've added link to another answer, which explains that in detail.